# Rails 3.0.12 Performance test issues

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, performance-testing

I'm trying to run benchmark and performance tests and I'm not getting the metrics displaying...

ruby -v:

`ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-linux]`

rvm list:

`=> ruby-1.9.2-p320-perf [ x86_64 ]`

the result of running `rake test:profile`:

```
BrowsingTest#test_homepage (130 ms warmup)
        process_time: 18446744073.71 sec
              memory: unsupported
             objects: unsupported
BrowsingTest#test_intel_companies_newstats (34 ms warmup)
        process_time: 26 ms
              memory: unsupported
             objects: unsupported
```

and running `rake test:benchmark`

```
BrowsingTest#test_homepage (103 ms warmup)
           wall_time: 23 ms
              memory: 0.00 KB
             objects: 0
             gc_runs: 0
             gc_time: 0.00 ms
BrowsingTest#test_intel_companies_newstats (31 ms warmup)
           wall_time: 9 ms
              memory: 0.00 KB
             objects: 0
             gc_runs: 0
             gc_time: 0.00 ms
```

my gem file

```
group :test do
    gem 'capybara'

    # for performance tests
    gem 'ruby-prof', :git => 'git://github.com/wycats/ruby-prof.git'
    gem 'test-unit'
end
```

When I tried to run:

`rvm install 1.9.2 --patch gcdata --name perf`

I got:

```
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/victor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320-perf, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.2-p320-perf - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.2-p320-perf - #extracting ruby-1.9.2-p320 to /home/victor/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320-perf
ruby-1.9.2-p320-perf - #extracted to /home/victor/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320-perf
Patch 'gcdata' not found.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed you need the patched gc.
But this patch is not available for all rubies. For ruby 1.9.2 you will have to use patch 290.
So the following should work just fine

```
rvm install 1.9.2-p290 --patch gcdata
```

Comment: Any thoughts on how one might determine whether the patch is available for the version of Ruby they use?

Comment: I used the rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/performance_testing.html#installing-gc-patched-mri You can also look at https://github.com/skaes/rvm-patchsets